# How can I plot the 5 year running mean of percentiles in a data set using Python and NumPy?

Tags: python, rolling-computation, percentile

I am trying to plot the 5 year running mean of the percentile within a set of data (to see how the percentile changes over time) but am having some trouble.

This is what my code currently looks like:
``

```
# Calculate running mean for each percentile in control_data
    control_percentiles = np.percentile(control_data[y_col], [25, 50, 75])
    control_running_means = [control_data[control_data[y_col] <= p][y_col].rolling(window_size, center=True).mean()
                             for p in control_percentiles]

    # Plot running means for each percentile in control_data
    for i, running_mean in enumerate(control_running_means):
           sns.lineplot(data= running_mean, x= control_data[x_col], y=running_mean, ax=axes[1], color=colors[i], ci=None)
```

And I have tried to create a for loop like this:

``

```
# Calculate running mean for each percentile in future_data
    control_percentiles=[]
    percentile_25=[]
    percentile_50=[]
    percentile_75=[]
    for i in control_data[x_col]:
         control_percentile_calculations = np.percentile(control_data[y_col], [25, 50, 75])
         percentile_25.append(control_percentile_calculations [0])
         percentile_50.append(control_percentile_calculations [1])
         percentile_75.append(control_percentile_calculations [2])
         control_percentiles.append(control_percentile_calculations )
```

But with no success so far. The idea is to see the change in percentile as x increases.